# skype freezes desktop on start

Tags: 11.04, freeze, skype

I have the latest version of Skype 64b installed in Natty x64 with gnome2. I downloaded the deb file from the official page (skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_amd64).

I had been working ok since i first installed it a couple of months ago but since last week whenever i click on the icon to open it the whole desktop freezes, actually it starts lagging, like the mouse takes a while to answer every 2 secs, sometimes it stays like that until Skype automatically force closes or the desktop freezes completely.

I looked around in google but the best answer i got was to re-install. It actually worked, but only once, second time i tried to open it same behavior reappeared.
Any help someone can give will be most appreciated.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).